# Dependent fields yii2

Tags: yii2, field, onchange

I need 2 dependent fields in framework Yii2 Example:

[image: 2 fields in ActiveForm]

I want when i insert in "Numero de Personas"= 5 or other numeric value, automatically "Consumo de Agua"= 2 * "Numero de Personas" = 10.
I saw onchange yii2 but i don't know how use it, i think onchange yii2 is an alternative.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'NUM_PERSONAS')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'AGUA_CONSUMO')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

**Update:**

With 2 calculated fields example:

```
$("#consumo-form #{$aguaId},#consumo-form #{$personaId}").on("keyup", function (e) {
        var persona = $("#consumo-form #{$personaId}").val();
        var agua = $("#consumo-form #{$aguaId}").val();
        $("#consumo-form #{$indConsumoAguaM}").val(persona*agua)
    });
```

Comment: But if someone insert 5 `Numero de Personas` he can change the `Consumo de Agua`? Or this relation 1 to 2 will always auto-completed for both inserts (inserting one, will auto-complete the other always) ?

Comment: I insert 5 "Numero de Personas"(Example), but i don't modify "Consumo de Agua", and when i insert one, will auto-complete the other always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the approach i would use:

in your **view**:

```
<?php
    $personaId = Html::getInputId($model, 'NUM_PERSONAS');
    $aguaId = Html::getInputId($model, 'AGUA_CONSUMO');
?>

    <!-- Begin of form -->
    <?= $form->field($model, 'NUM_PERSONAS')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'AGUA_CONSUMO')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <!-- End of form -->

<?php
$js = <<<JS
$("#my-form-id #{$personaId}").on("keyup", function (e) {
    var persona = $(this).val();
    $("#my-form-id #{$aguaId}").val(persona*2)
});
$("#my-form-id #{$aguaId}").on("keyup", function (e) {
    var agua = $(this).val()%2 == 0 ? $(this).val() : $(this).val() - 1;
    $("#my-form-id #{$personaId}").val(agua/2)
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

With that, both fields will try to auto-complete after the other being changed. But, just to be safe, we need to add a validation on model's rules also.

In your **Model**:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        // Your rules 
        [['NUM_PERSONAS', 'AGUA_CONSUMO'], 'checkValues']
    ];
}

public function checkValues($attribute)
{
    $persona = $this->NUM_PERSONAS;
    $agua = $this->AGUA_CONSUMO%2 == 0 ? $this->AGUA_CONSUMO : $this->AGUA_CONSUMO - 1;
    if ($persona != $agua/2) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'Error message');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i have a new problem i need do dependent fields with 2 parameters i try this but doesn't work: `$("#consumo-form #{$aguaId},#consumo-form #{$personaId}").on("keyup", function (e) {
        var persona = $(this).val();
        var agua = $(this).val();
        var total = persona/agua;
        $("#consumo-form #{$indConsumoAguaM}").val(total)
    });` but always the result is 1

Comment: You are setting the same value for `var persona` and `var agua`. So, it will always return `1`. Can you update the question and add this information? (it's more readable there)